# Assets 2: Image Manipulations not showing for images in subfolders?

Tags: assets, file-uploads, file-manager, thumbnails

This title should be pretty self-explanatory. All the images and their manipulations are working just fine. Except when I upload the images into a subfolder of the main "`images`" upload-directory.

When I tell it to get the so-called "gallerythumb"-manipulation of said image, it returns the url: 
`/images/store-photos/_gallerythumb/111.jpg`

Which corresponds to the usual pattern:
`/upload-directory-path/user-created-subfolder/_manipulation-name/filename.jpg`

Is this something that was never a part of Assets' functionality? I mean, I know it's not part of EE's functionality, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a permissions issue to me. Make sure that the subfolders of the upload folders are writable by PHP. Image manipulations work for subfolders in Assets.

Comment: Andris! Thanks for your feedback :) We run our EE-installation on a Windows server, though. Permissions are never really an issue there... I've run into this problem before, on some other sites we made. Same story. Maybe it's tripping over the path-inconsistency or something? (forward/ and backward\-slashes) This is usually easily fixed by using PHP's [realpath](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php).

Comment: I can imagine you guys not having the time/resources to work this out on a Windows-server... Any pointers where /how I might go about fixing this myself?

Comment: Adrian, if you can send over CP access to support@pixelandtonic.com, I can take a closer look, pinpoint the issue and, hopefully, fix it for the next upcoming release :)

Comment: Andris had a look, and apparently this issue was already addressed in Assets 2.2.2 :) Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken but EE only sees one level of folder and by thereby only manipulate those in he top level folder.

Assets introduced sub folders and as far as I know not even EE file  manager sees IMG in assets sub folders.